# Commerce Manage Settings for User Groups

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, user-groups

When setting User Group permissions for users for Craft Commerce, there are explicit options for:

- Manage Orders
- Manage Products
- Manage Promotions

But nothing is listed for **Manage Settings**. Is this not controllable for User Groups? Seems like it definitely should be... some users would be allowed to manage product info but not Settings, while some users would need access to Settings for updating Tax or Shipping options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not a native Commerce feature, but feel free to add a thumbs-up/comment to this feature request, which is what you're asking for: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1082

Comment: Ok - thanks Brad. Hope this gets addressed... especially when it seems to be a pretty well established convention for many third party plugins to offer separate permissions for their Settings pages.